# S3 bucket of a specific region to another S3 bucket of another specific region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How I can transfer the content of a S3 bucket of a specific region to another S3 bucket of another specific region? Please provide the simplest way and detailed steps if you can

Comment: Hey Raghuram, welcome to StackOverflow! In order to maximize the quality of conversation, members of our community encourage (and expect) independent research done to solve a problem. This helps us converse (and point people in the right direction) better. Could you update your question with any information that you've managed to find so far (along with the issues you've faced)? We'll be more than happy to follow up on that.

Comment: Do you wish to perform a one-off copy, or copy objects on a continual basis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to synchronize S3 bucket contents. For example:

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket1/ s3://mybucket2/
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create two buckets in a different region as per your needs, then sync data in a bucket with each other using following command in awscli.

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket1/ s3://mybucket2/

aws s3 sync s3://mybucket2/ s3://mybucket3/
```